# mixxx is not working properly

Tags: sound-juicer, mixxx

i have installed "mixxx virtual dj" in my Ubuntu 14.04 but its not working properly. it has added my music and shows running the same but sound is not there and at the same time all other software which are running audio also stops running and go on pause. Please tell me something

Answer (score -1):

Mixxx is started with pasuspender which disables the desktop sound and has its own sound setup. Be sure you have selected a proper sound hardware in hardware preferences.

For further questions go to http://www.mixxx.org/forums/

Comment: Can you provide more details please?